# Can you follow a OneDrive folder or OneDrive in SharePoint2013

Tags: onedrive

So essentially I would like to know if a user can follow a OneDrive or OneDrive Folder in SharePoint in the same way you follow a site. So when you go to sites you can see the folder/OneDrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User's can't follow onedrive documents.

Also in the latest release in SharePoint online the followed document link is taken off. In order to see the followed documents you should switch back to classic mode.

Comment: Cheers I thought that was the case I just needed a sanity check.